# Countdown data incorreta

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directives, countdown

Estou utilizando o [Countdownjs](http://countdownjs.org/) para inserir uma contagem em meu projeto porém ele está retornando o dia incorreto.
Estou utilizando AngularJS, segue abaixo a diretiva que criei para a contagem:

```
.directive('tempoPercorrido', function($interval){
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                var timeNow = new Date(attrs.tempoPercorrido);
                var units = countdown.ALL;
                var timespan = countdown(timeNow, null, units, 0, 0);                    

                function updateTme(){
                    var timespan = countdown(timeNow, null, units, 0, 0);
                    var dias = timespan.days <= 9 ? '0' + timespan.days.toString() : timespan.days.toString();
                    var horas = timespan.hours <= 9 ? '0' + timespan.hours.toString() : timespan.hours.toString();
                    var minutos = timespan.minutes <= 9 ? '0' + timespan.minutes.toString() : timespan.minutes.toString();
                    var segundos = timespan.seconds <= 9 ? '0' + timespan.seconds.toString() : timespan.seconds.toString();

                    var contador = '<div class="dias circulo">'+ dias + '</div>'+
                           '<div class="horas circulo">'+ horas + '</div>'+
                           '<div class="minutos circulo">'+ minutos + '</div>'+
                           '<div class="segundos circulo">'+ segundos + '</div>';
                    //console.log(timespan);
                    $(element).html(contador);       
                }

                updateTme();

                $interval(function(){
                    updateTme();
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    })
```

No HTML, inseri o seguinte dado:

```
<div class="horario_banner" tempo-percorrido="2017-10-29 00:00:00"></div>
```

Porém para esta data está retornando 06 dias 08 horas 50 min e os segundos decorrentes.
Sendo que na verdade deveria retornar mais de 100 dias.

Caso ativo o console do timespan ele retorna o seguinte dado:

n {start: Sun Oct 29 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão), end: Wed Mar 15 2017 15:11:13 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil), units: 2047, value: -19640926732, millennia: 0…}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema eu encontrei, está na var units, ele está pegando  o mês também, e não somente os dias, horas minutos e segundos, o problema é que não sei como faço para tirar o mês e pegar somente os dias, horas, minutos e segundos.

Answer (score 1):

Você está pegando Tudo na variável units, fazendo com que a semana e mês também sejam somados.
Utilize a variável units da seguinte maneira:

```
var units = countdown.DAYS | countdown.HOURS | countdown.MINUTES | countdown.SECONDS;
```

Assim somarão somente os dias, horas, minutos e segundos.

Answer (score -1):

Testa aqui meu brother.. :)

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

```
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2019 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o seu código? Muitas vezes um trecho de código que é trivial para você pode não ser compreendido tão facilmente por outros usuários, então uma explicação em texto sempre é bem-vinda :D